# Multiple Java and Ant

Tags: java, ant

I would like get you advise on the following issue. I need to have both Java 6 and Java 7 to run on my machine. At the same time, I also need to have ant installed.

Therefore, I understand I need to edit the environment variables. I have setup accoirdinly accordinly as shown below but when I type ant or java -version on cmd both the commands are indicating as  not reconised. Please advice on this issue.

Environtment Variables (System Variables)

```
ANT_HOME = C:\apache\ant
JAVA_6 = C:\Progra~2\Java\jre6
JAVA_7 = C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre
JAVA_HOME = %JAVA_6% (or JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_7%)
PATH = %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%\bin
```

After setting the following amendments in my environment varibales, Both ant -version, java -version commands give me "Java.exe" is not recongined

Comment: you need to open a new command prompt window to get these reflected

Comment: @Sanjeev So is my settings are correct??

Comment: Yup settings are fine. try to echo them and check the values. for e.g. `echo %JAVA_HOME%`

Comment: @Sanjeev The echos are working fine...But I still cant use the ant -version and java -version

Comment: What is the output of echo %PATH%

Comment: @Sanjeev Thanks alot Sanjeev, after i restart the com it worked well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I restarted the pc, It worked properly.